# How do I properly include an npm run test command in docker run?

Tags: docker, npm, travis-ci

I am sure I have run this command before, but I tested the following command in my terminal and got this error:

```
✗ docker run aa1112d76852 npm run test -- --coverage
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I am concerned because this is the command with the exception of the container id, that I will be placing in my `.travis.yml` file. Where is the error in how I put it together this time?

This is my `Dockerfile` configuration:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder 
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked previously because I was building it from `Dockerfile.dev` which has this last command that is crucial:

```
FROM node:alpine

 WORKDIR '/app'

 COPY package.json .
 RUN npm install

 COPY . .

 CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Whereas the new container I was using was built from `Dockerfile` which has this configuration:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder 
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Notice the missing `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`.

So the command should work in my `.travis.yml` file because I build it with my `Dockerfile.dev` like so:

```
before_install:
  - docker build -t danale/docker-react -f Dockerfile.dev .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for context, this question is related to the "Docker and Kubernetes: The Complete Guide" course on Udemy which is fairly well-recommended on Reddit etc.

This error occurs when you pass the image ID for the production build (created using the Dockerfile) rather than the image ID of the Dockerfile.dev:

```
root@ubuntu-docker:/home/paul/frontend# docker run USERNAME/docker-react npm run test
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable 
file not found in $PATH": unknown.

root@ubuntu-docker:/home/paul/frontend# docker run USERNAME/docker-react-dev npm run 
test

> frontend@0.1.0 test /app
> react-scripts test

PASS src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders without crashing (92ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.794s
Ran all test suites.
```

I believe it's because the Dockerfile.dev has the line "npm run start" which starts the development server and then allows it to receive the test command, whereas the production version just builds the app then serves it using nginx. I'm not familiar enough with React to really get my head around it.

However if anyone else (like the OP, and me) was doing the course and struggling with this error, I hope this helped.